# Connection String and Connecting to SQL DB

Tags: postgresql, connection, database-connection

Im hosting a local postgres db and am trying to find open-source programs that will be able to connect to said db so that I can generate reports based on the data.

While I know Jasper is a thing, Im trying to see if there are alternatives and I came across 2:

[EasyReport](https://easy.report/)

[Seal Report](https://sealreport.org/)

Both of these ask for `Connection Strings` that Im not really familiar with.
Came across a [site explaining it](https://www.connectionstrings.com/connection-strings-explained/), but Im still unsure of the format.

```
Provider=PostgreSQL OLE DB Provider;Data Source=myServerAddress;location=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;password=myPassword;
```

```
Driver={PostgreSQL};Server=IP address;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Above are some of the examples the site provided with, but Im still confused. What is the `Driver`? What is the `Provider`? The site's examples werent cleared on what are these 2 are supposed to be.

I tried creating a `Connection String` based on the example:

```
Provider=PostgreSQLData;Data Source=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<myDBName>;location=<myDBName>;User ID=<myDBUsername>;password=<myDBPassword>;timeout=1000;
```

This fails. Something about `Provider not found` and `Could not connect to database: Couldn't set provider`

Comment: First, figure out what API the program uses. Does it use the PostgreSQL C-API? the PostgreSQL JDBC driver? ODBC? The answer will depend on that.

Comment: ```EasyReport```, Im not sure. All I can select is the Database type (selected ```PostgreSQL```). Likewise for ```Seal Report```, their Connection/Database Type includes OleDB, ODBC, MySQL, MongoDB, MSSSQL (System.Data), MSSSQL (Microsoft.Data), Oracle. For this one, I tried both ```ODBC``` and ```OleDB```.

Comment: That's lame, they don't support PostgreSQL specifically, so you will have to use the ODBC driver. How to setup an ODBC data source depends on your operating system. Try to find tools that support PostgreSQL directly!

Comment: Really? It was already mentioned for ```Seal Report``` about lack of support, but doesnt ```EasyReport``` have an option for Postgres as mentioned...?

Comment: Looking at the web site, they seem to do. Did you try asking them how to do it? Is the documentation that bad?

Comment: Well...they do have this: "Don't know how to get a connection string for your DB?
Use ConnectionStrings.com to find out" which lead to the question in my opening post, because Im not sure what is the ```Driver``` and ```Provider``` they're asking for. Is it a jar file? A library? Does it need to be installed? Do I even need to provide it, since the site is web-based? These are not that clear to me. Are they expecting ```org.postgresql.Driver``` as the driver?

Comment: I don't know. Try a [normal PostgreSQL connection string](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) first.